# Relationship trouble with Doctrine PHP

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have doctrine set up on a site and I'm having trouble with relationships.  I have an account object that has many profiles.  Each profile has one account.  When I try to create a new profile and persist then flush, the form hangs and does nothing.  If I remove the flush I get the debug statements print, but nothing is persisted.

The model properties.

In account

```
/**
 *  The profiles belonging to this account. 
 *
 *  @OneToMany(targetEntity="Profile_Model_Profile", mappedBy="account")
 */
protected $profiles;
```

In Profile

```
/**
  * The account that owns this profile
  *
  * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Account_Model_Account", 
                inversedBy="profiles", 
                cascade={"detach", "persist", "merge"}, 
                fetch="EAGER")
  * @JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
protected $account;
```

The creation (after setting all properties)

```
 $profile->setAccount($account);
 $account->addProfile($profile);

 $em->persist($profile);
 $em->persist($account);
 $em->flush();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: From the question title it sounds like you should've bought Doctrine PHP a Valentine's day present and not spent so much time checking out all the other hot frameworks that came along.

Comment: If I just persist the account I have the same issue.  If I flush() afterward, nothing happens.  If I don't the flow of execution continues, but nothing is persisted.

Comment: My suspicion is that there's some kind of recursive issue here that's making it hang on flush().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just revisited this.  I saw in the Safari Web Inspector that I was getting a 500 error when trying to persist the account.  It just wasn't showing anything on the screen.  As per this post, [Codeigniter and Doctrine 500 internal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101691/codeigniter-and-doctrine-500-internal-error), I wrapped everything in a try catch using \Exception instead of Exception and was able to get details about why it was crashing.

```
 try{
      ...
 }catch (\Exception $e) {            
      echo "<pre>Error: " . $e . "</pre>";
 }
```